# Bootstrap 4 nested row and columns, adds whitespace on the right on mobile view

Tags: html, css, user-interface, bootstrap-4, responsive-design

I'm trying to nest **3 columns**(col-lg-4) inside **a column**(col-lg-9) and it seems it's not following Bootstrap's 12 column grid system. [Documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)

And although it looks fine on a desktop view, but gives a whitespace on the right hand side of a the mobile view. Can someone spot the error please?

Thanks.

Navbar :

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md black-bg fixed-top opacity70">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
              <img src="logosmall.png" alt="logo">
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
              <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto font-weight700">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#" >HOME</a>
                  </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#" >SOLUTIONS</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link text-white" href="contact.html" >INDUSTRIES</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link text-white" href="about-us.html" >CAREERS</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link text-white" href="about-us.html" >DISCOVER PTS</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link text-white" href="about-us.html" >CONTACT US</a>
                  </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </nav>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-pts-gray btn-lg btn-block btn-padd-bottom btn-size-small"> Title 1</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-pts btn-lg btn-block btn-padd-bottom btn-size-small">Title 2</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-9">
        <h3>Awards & Recognition</h3>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="card">
                    <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
            </div>

            
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="card">
                    <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="card">
                    <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Main code

```
    <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <div class="card">
                        <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                        <div class="card-body">
                          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <div class="card">
                        <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                        <div class="card-body">
                          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <div class="card">
                        <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                        <div class="card-body">
                          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <div class="card">
                        <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                        <div class="card-body">
                          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <div class="card">
                        <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                        <div class="card-body">
                          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <div class="card">
                        <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                        <div class="card-body">
                          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Custom CSS :

```
.black-bg {
    background-color: black;
}

.opacity70 {
    opacity: 70%;
}

.jumbotron-hero {
    background-image: url("pics/unsplash1.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100vh;
}

.padd-top-50{
    padding-top: 200px;
}

.padd-top-20{
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.padd-top-down-40
{
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.pts-title-blue {
    color : #00232d;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding-top: 30px;
}

.gray-background {
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
}

.btn-pts {
    color: #3cb2cc;
    background-color: #032934;
    border-color: #032934;
    border-radius: inherit;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.btn-pts:hover{
    color: #3cb2cc;
}

p {
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #6c757d!important;
}

.pts-light-blue{
    color: #3cb2cc;
}

.card-blue {
    background-color: #3cb2cc;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 { font-weight: 700;}

.jumboton-bottom {
    background-color: #032934;
    border-radius: 0rem;
}

.no-margin {
    margin-right: 40px; 
    margin-left: 40px;
}

.big-fonts {
    font-size: 4.5rem;
}

.p-bold{
    font-weight: 700;
}

.light-blue-bg{
    background-color: #3cb2cc;
}

.btn-light-blue {
    color: white;
    background-color: #3cb2cc;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: white !important;
    padding: 15px;
}

.bigger-h1 {
    font-size: 4.5rem;
}

.idea-css {
    font-size: 5rem;
    background-color: #032934;
    color: #3cb2cc;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    border-color: darkgray;
}

.dot {
    height: 125px;
    width: 125px;
    background-color: #3cb2cc;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
  }

  .padd-icon-dot {
    padding-top: 33px;
  }

  .v-divider {
    border-right: 2px solid #3cb2cc;
  }

  .jumbotron-solutions {
    background-image: url("pics/unsplash1.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    height: 50vh;
  }

  .padd-top-100 {
      padding-top: 100px;
  }

  .btn-padd-bottom {
      padding-bottom: 10px;
  }

  .btn-size-small {
    font-size: 1rem;
  }

  .btn-pts-gray {
    color: #032934;
    background-color: #d5d5d5;
    border-color: #d5d5d5;
    border-radius: inherit;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.card-gray-bg {
    background-color: #d5d5d5;
}

.font-weight700 {
    font-weight: 700;
}

.font-weight900 {
    font-weight: 900;
}

.social-images{
    max-height: 30px; 
    max-width: 30px;
}

.btn-light-pts {
        color: white;
        background-color: #3cb2cc;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: 3cb2cc !important;
        border-radius: 0rem;
}
```

Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]
[image: Screenshot2]

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot and any custom CSS outside of bootstrap's that you're using relative to this code?

Comment: Hi @AJ47 custom CSS and screenshot added

Comment: I'm wondering if you have some extra CSS affecting the columns, here's how it looks with default bootstrap: https://jsfiddle.net/ajk47/1obew9gh/1/

Comment: @AJ47 adding the entire custom CSS file. It's strange, i added the whole CSS on your fiddle, works fine there.. but not in my machine :(

Comment: Including any other extra CSS files? When you inspect element, is it adding extra margin / padding to the right?

Comment: Hi @AJ47 that is the only custom css. Added another screenshot, the blue area displays when hover on chrome inspect on "body" and "html". It seems the navbar is taking extra width.. there doesn't seem to be extra padding or margin there.

Comment: Can you include the navbar in your code / fiddle? that seems to be where the issue is.

Comment: Navbar added, however it's quite standard